# How do i modify the layout of the default registration page

Tags: magento-1.9

How would i move the custom **PixelPin Connect block** above the **Personal information block**?

[image]

Here's the layout page (pixelpin_connect.xml)

```
<customer_account_create>        
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>pixelpin_connect/css/styles.css</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="customer_form_register">
            <action method="setTemplate" >
                <template>pixelpin/connect/customer/form/register.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <block type="pixelpin_connect/register" name="pixelpin_connect_register">
              <block type="pixelpin_connect/pixelpin_button" name="pixelpin_connect_checkout_pixelpin_button" />
            </block>
        </reference>        
    </customer_account_create>
```

register.phtml:

```
<div class="pixelpin-connect-register">   
<div class="<?php echo $this->_getColSet(); ?>">
    <?php if($this->_pixelpinEnabled()): ?>
    <div class="<?php echo $this->_getCol(); ?> pixelpin-connect-register-pixelpin">
        <div class="fieldset">
            <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Pixelpin Connect') ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $this->__('You can register using your Pixelpin account.') ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('pixelpin_connect_checkout_pixelpin_button')?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('pixelpin_connect_checkout_pixelpin_button')
```

above to the form in **register.phtml** ?

Comment: Made changes in edit featuring register.phtml